# How to call or pass method from Screen B to Screen A in react native?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have two screens, Screen A and Screen B. In which screen B has a state which needs to be passed to Screen A and i have achieved that using react navigation by sending params via navigation. The problem is i need to call a method is Screen A when a button is clicked in Screen B ( when the button is clicked it navigates to Screen A ) and along with navigation ends i need to call a method to perform setState.

How to achieve this ?

My Method:

```
 handler(){
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
    }
```

So when user clicks on a button ("Apply") in Screen B the button will call navigation. So how to call   handler() when user clicks on button at Screen B ?

Comment: There's probably a few ways to go about doing this and its hard to help without the full code from both screens here. Are you completely closing screen A when moving to screen B or are you using a stack navigator where screen A stays in memory?

Comment: Using Stack, where it stays in memory !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach, using navigation params, is to put a condition in the componentDidMount of screenA calling your handler() if you detect that the param you sent from screenB exists. Something like this (not sure about the exactly writing):

screenB

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenA', { paramFromB: 'param passed from Screen B'}
```

screenA

```
componentDidMout(){
  if(this.props.navigation.state.params.paramFromB){
   this.handler()
  }
}
```

so every time you enter in screen A it will check if the param from screen B exists and then call your handler

Comment: componentDidMout wont render every time when we go back to screen !

Comment: @hellodevs are you overriding your goBack button? You could override it and instead of using navigation.navigate you use navigation.push to go back to Screen A. Using push allows us to express the intent to add another route regardless of the existing navigation history.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#going-back more details here in the section Navigate to a route multiple times